# Git selective merge of content in thesame file

Tags: git, merge

I performed a git merge between two branches with selective commit to certain parts of the code, not all, on one particular file (call it X).

Now i want to merge in the remaining code which i did not merge in the previous step but for some reason git gives me that branches already up to date, although there is a difference between the two X files on the two branches.

Is there a way to resolve this? I might be misunderstanding how merge works

Cheers